# How to order by a boolean field in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, kanban

I can't understand the behaviour of the Odoo API. It's driving me crazy.

As you may know, if you want to order a model by some of its fields, you have to modify the attribute `_order` of the model. It works fine.

Now, suppose you want to order a specific view by some fields without altering the normal order of the model (this means: order a specific view by some fields and the rest of the views of the same model by other fields).

In this case, you have to use XML code, specifying the attribute `default_order` in the `kanban` or `tree` tag, depending on which view you are modifying.

I've used this in the past succesfully. So I wanted to apply this again to a kanban view (this time I want to order by a *boolean* field, a *char* and another *char*).

Now my surprise: ordering by a *boolean* field reverses the order of the next fields if it values `False`.

***e.g.*** We have 6 records, which we want to order by a boolean, the name, and surname; in a kanban view with `default_order`:

- True, John, Doe
- True, Jane, Doe
- True, John, Xoe
- False, John, Die
- False, Jane, Die
- False, Jane, Xie

So in the example, in the kanban view we'll see them ordered this way:

1. True, Jane, Doe
2. True, John, Doe
3. True, John, Xoe
4. False, John, Die
5. False, Jane, Xie
6. False, Jane, Die

As you can see, if the boolean values `True`, the records are ordered by **boolean**, **name** and **surname**, which is what I want. But if it values `False`, the records are ordered by **boolean**, **name DESC**, **surname DESC**.

What's going on? Did you experience the same? How can I order by a *boolean*, then a *char*, and then another *char*??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I use to to odd sortsis use the context to control it.  In the window action for the kanban view, add a context like

```
<field name="context">{'do_my_special_sort': True}</field>
```

and then on the model, override the search method, check for this flag in the context and set the sort order.

Comment: Thank you very much @Adrian! That's a good way to manage that. But in my case, the kanban view is inside a `one2many` field inside a form (it's exactly the same case as the field `child_ids` in the `res.partner` form view). So I have to modify the context in the action which calls the form, don't I? And then, will the search order affect to the kanban view inside the field?

Comment: You should be able to just put a context on the <field> definition of the one2many but you may need to try a couple of things.

Comment: It works with the context in the field. The workaround I had done earlier was creating another field of type `Char` which had a compute depending on the boolean field and with `store=True`. This `Char` stored the value of the boolean converted into a string. So then, in the kanban, I was able to order by the boolean through this `Char`. But I think your solution is righter and better. Thank you @Adrian!